# sending data from a servlet javaEE to an angular component

Tags: angular, web, servlets, jakarta-ee

am a beginner in javaEE,I work with angular in FrontEnd and javaEE in BackEnd.I want to send data from a servlet to an angular component and I wanna know if is it possible what instruction i should include in my servlet,in this example i wanna send the list of users(utilisateurs) to angular component for treatment,here is my code of servlet.
ps1: I use module HttpClient in angular.
ps2: I don't use Spring framework.

Test.java

```
package com.coors.servlets;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.octest.beans.Utilisateur;
import com.octest.dao.DaoFactory;
import com.octest.dao.UtilisateurDao;
import com.octest.dao.UtilisateurDaoImpl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/test")
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private UtilisateurDao utilisateurDao;
private DaoFactory daoFactory; 

public Test() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    daoFactory=DaoFactory.getInstance();
    utilisateurDao=daoFactory.getUtilisateurDao();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    this.utilisateurDao.lister();//I  get the list of users

    //here what instruction ?????????????????????????????????????????
}

public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say I am calling this URL http://localhost:8080/StackOverflow/test where test is the urlPattern from my servlet. So when I send this URL in the browser, the doGet method is triggered. In the doGet I could do so:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add("User 1");
    myList.add("User 2");
    request.setAttribute("users", myList);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("second.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

I created a list and set the content in the attribute users I am passing to an existing page called second.jsp.

If you are using Maven, include this in your dependencies so you could use jstl in second.jsp to see the content.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2

With jstl you can access the contents from the attribute "users" with ${users}.

More to jstl [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>  
<meta charset="utf 8">
<title>Aloha</title>     
</head>  
<body ng-app="app">
<h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{message}}</h1>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
<script>  
angular.module("app", []).controller("HelloWorldCtrl", function($scope) {  
$scope.message="Hello JSP DATA: ${users}" 
} )
</script>
```

This way you can send the data to the page and access inside your Angular app with ${yourparametername}.

The result:

[image]

If you want to use the response from servlet, it could look like this encoding the users but not the & or = symbols to build the URL properly:

```
    String urlUsers= "";
    for(String u : angularList) {
        urlUsers +=                      "users="+URLEncoder.encode(u,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())+"&";
    }
    urlUsers = urlUsers.substring(0,urlUsers.length()-1);

    response.sendRedirect("angular.jsp?"+urlUsers);
```

The URL in the angular.jsp page will be:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/angular.jsp?users=User+1&users=User+2
```

Now its with Angular to get the values from the URL.

Comment: i agree with u ,but I work with Angular in Frontend not with jsp pages,my question is how to send send data from servlet (response) to an angular component?

Comment: I updated the answer with an angular mini-app and also using the response. Now you have two ways to get the data in the page where the angular app is living in.